# What values can we use in `formattingControls` parameter in RichText component

Tags: customization, block-editor

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/richtext/) says:

- `formattingControls={ [ 'bold', 'italic' ] } // Allow the content to be made bold or italic, but do not allow other formatting options`

... but I can't find a list of all the values ​​that we can use there.

I know about `bold`, `italic`, `link`, `strikethrough` but there are more elements.

So what is the complete list of supported values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what is the complete list of supported values?

The list of available format types is maintained in the `core/rich-text` store. You can query the store by running this code in your browser's console, which will return an array containing the format types:

```js
wp.data.select( 'core/rich-text' ).getFormatTypes();
```

And as of writing, there are 10 default/core format types: `bold`, `code`, `image`, `italic`, `link`, `strikethrough`, `underline`, `text-color`, `subscript`, and `superscript`. (Note: I intentionally omitted the namespace, which is `core` as in `core/bold`.)

**References:** [Introduction to the Format API » Register a New Format](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/format-api/1-register-format.md) and the [`@wordpress/format-library` package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/format-library).

#### But `formattingControls` is deprecated. Use `allowedFormats` instead.

The `formattingControls` prop(erty), although still works as of writing, has long been [deprecated](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/CHANGELOG.md#300-2019-08-05) (in August 2019), and you should now use its replacement: [`allowedFormats`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md#allowedformats-array).

Both `allowedFormats` and `formattingControls` accept an array of format names, but with two differences:

1. With `formattingControls`, you don't need to specify the namespace, i.e. if the full name is `core/bold`, you only need to use `bold`.

   Secondly, *custom format types are not supported* — they won't cause any error, but they won't appear in (or be added to) the Rich Text toolbar, either.
2. With `allowedFormats`, you need to specify the full format name including namespace, e.g. `core/bold` and `core/italic`.

   And that's because *`allowedFormats` supports custom format types*. So for example, if you've registered the [sample format here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/format-api/3-apply-format.md) (named `my-custom-format/sample-output`), then you'd set the `allowedFormats` like so:

   ```js
   allowedFormats={ [ 'core/bold', 'core/italic', 'my-custom-format/sample-output' ] }
   ```